# Noetherian localizations and extra-condition implies Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve this question but I'm stucked:

> If a ring $R$ satisfies the following two conditions:
>
> i) For every maximal ideal $M$ of $R$, if $S = R\setminus M$ then $S^{-1}R$ is Noetherian,
>
> ii) For every $x \in R$, $x\neq 0$, the set of maximal ideals that contains $x$ is finite,
>
> then $R$ is Noetherian.

I tried to show that every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated but I don't get anything with this.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: I have already proved it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263586/noetherianity-is-a-local-property).

Comment: Thank you, and Sorry for duplicate the post!