# Can we give an ring $R$ such that every prime ideal of $R$ be maximal with $|\operatorname{Max}(R)|=\infty?$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

It is well known that in commutative rings, maximal ideals are prime.

> Can we give an example of a ring $R$ such that every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal with $|\operatorname{Max}(R)|=\infty?$

Answer (score 3):

This condition is equivalent to having [Krull dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) zero. Every [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring) has this property (quotients of Boolean rings are Boolean, and the only Boolean ring which is also an integral domain is $\mathbb{F}_2$, which is a field), and a Boolean ring has finitely many maximal ideals iff it's finite. So an example is given by any infinite Boolean ring such as $\prod_I \mathbb{F}_2$ for any infinite set $I$.

The spectrum of this ring can be identified with the space $\beta I$ of ultrafilters on $I$. For more details see, for example, [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/11/22/boolean-rings-ultrafilters-and-stones-representation-theorem/).

Answer (score 2):

If $R=\mathbb F_2^{\mathbb N}$ then $\dim R=0$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210940/show-that-any-prime-ideal-from-such-a-ring-is-maximal)) and since it is not noetherian must have infinitely many maximal ideals ([why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263605/121097)).

**Remark.**

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $\dim R=0$. Then $R$ is semilocal iff $R/N(R)$ is noetherian.

If $R$ is semilocal, then $N(R)$ is a finite intersection of maximal ideals, so $R/N(R)$ is isomorphic to a finite direct product of fields.
Conversely, if $R/N(R)$ is noetherian, then $R/N(R)$ is artinian, so it is semilocal. But $R$ and $R/N(R)$ have the same prime ideals, so $R$ is semilocal.

Comment: In fact, a commutative ring $R$ is zero-dimensional iff $R/N(R)$ is [von Neumann regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_regular_ring). If you suppose $R$ reduced, then this is equivalent to $R$ von Neumann regular. In particular, every boolean ring is such an example, and this explains why I've chosen that example.