# Examples of local properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring (commutative with $1$ and $0$). A property $P$ is said to be a *local property* if the following holds true:

$$A ~\text{has}~ P \iff A_{\mathfrak{p}} ~\text{has}~ P ~\text{for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$}$$

What are some examples of local properties? (specifically for rings, not modules)

Comment: Reduced, Cohen-Macaulay, Gorenstein.... A very important fact is that being the 0 module is also a local property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some local properties?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2321975/what-are-some-local-properties)

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Hmm, as written that post seems to be defining "local property" as "if all localizations of $R$ at prime ideals have property P, $R$ has property P."  This post specifies it is biconditional.  Don't have an example to distinguish, however. Good to link the post anyhow.

Comment: @rschwieb I don't think I have ever encountered a ring-theoretic property which is local-to-global but not global-to-local (in general, I guess any property which passes to subrings and (arbitrary) products is local-to-global)

Comment: @math54321 Yeah, nothing comes to mind for me either.

Comment: @rschwieb It just occurred to me that the property "has a nontrivial idempotent" is (vacuously) local-to-global, but not global-to-local (alternatively, any property which is never satisfied for local rings works)

Comment: @rschwieb Actually here is a much better example: the property "has trivial unit group" passes to subrings and products, but is not global-to-local. It is also not vacuously false for local rings, as there is a unique(!) local ring that satisfies it

Comment: @math54321 Yeah i was just trying to articulate that the vacuous thing wasn't satisfying.  Glad you found the new one.